# Error CS0556 User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type

Tags: c#, linq, casting

```
I have the following code:

public class SampleStartDateHistoryViewModel
    {
        public string modifiedBy;        
        public static explicit operator SampleStartDateHistoryViewModel(SampleStartDateHistoryModel startDateRecord)
        {
            return new SampleStartDateHistoryViewModel
            {
                modifiedBy = startDateRecord.modifiedBy
            };
        }        
        public static explicit operator List<SampleStartDateHistoryViewModel>(List<SampleStartDateHistoryModel> startDateRecords)
        {
            return startDateRecords.Select(zx => (SampleStartDateHistoryViewModel)zx).ToList<SampleStartDateHistoryViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

The cast between classes : SampleStartDateHistoryViewModel and SampleStartDateHistoryModel  works as expected.
But when converting List to List
Compilator generates an error as above
Error   CS0556  User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type

Answer (score 0):

The message says it all. Either the input or output type of your `explicit operator` must be the "enclosing type" `SampleStartDateHistoryViewModel`, you cannot convert between other types, such as lists.

Comment: We are talking about this cast :                                                                                        public static explicit operator List<SampleStartDateHistoryViewModel>(List<SampleStartDateHistoryModel> startDateRecords)
        {
            return startDateRecords.Select(zx => (SampleStartDateHistoryViewModel)zx).ToList<SampleStartDateHistoryViewModel>();
        }

Comment: @RomanZeleniy Yes. Your explicit operator converts from `List<SampleStartDateHistoryModel>`, to `List<SampleStartDateHistoryViewModel>`. None of these is the "enclosing type" `SampleStartDateHistoryViewModel`.